# recursive function error: "stack overflow"

Tags: c++, recursion

I wrote this function that supposed to find smallest positive integer that is divisible by every number 1 through 20. I get "stack overflow error", even though, when I test for numbers 1 through 10, it works just fine.
here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

// function prototype
int smallPos(int k, int m,int n);

int main(){
    printf("the smallest positive number that is divisible by 1 through 20 is %d ", smallPos(1,1,13));

}

int smallPos(int k, int n, int m){
    int div=0;
    for(int i = n;i<=m;i++) {
        if (k%i==0) 
            div++;
    } 
    if (div==m) {
        return k;
    } else {
        k+=1;
        smallPos(k,n,m);
    }   
}
```

Why does it happen? The number shouldn't be that big anyway.
Thank you!

Comment: Why is this even implemented as a recursive function, anyways?

Comment: This was a solution I could come up with.
I tried to use nested loops but got confused.

Comment: You could save yourself some looping and recurse on the first fail: `for(int i = n; i <= m; i++) if(k % i) return smallPos(k + 1, n, m); return k;` but the stack overflow will still exist.

Comment: Someone is doing project euler

Comment: @GKED: updated my answer with a working solution.

Answer (score 5):

The final condition (`div == m`) will never be true.  For `div` to become equal to `m`, the number `k` should be divisible by *all* of the numbers in range `[n,m)`.

**Edit**: I've reread the text in the `printf()` call to understand what the function does.  You're looking for the first number divisible by all numbers in the range.  If my calculations are correct, this number should be the product of all unique prime factors of the numbers in the range.  For the range `[1,13]` (as per the function call, not the text), this number should be:

```
30030 = 1 * 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 9 * 11 * 13
```

Now, this means you are going to invoke the function recursively over 30,000 times, which is obviously way too many times for the size of stack you're using (defaults are relatively small).  For a range this size, you should really consider writing an iterative function instead.

**Edit**: here's an iterative version that seems to work.

```
int smallPos ( int n, int m )
{
    int k = 0;
    while ( ++k )
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = n; i<=m; i++)
        {
            if (k%i==0) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        if (count == (m-n+1)) {
            return k;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

Indeed, the result for `smallPos(1,10)`, the result is 2520.  It seems my previous estimate was a lower bound, not a fixed result.

Comment: That will be true for a large number, which I yet to figure out :).
For example, the least positive integer that is divisible for all i 1:10 is 2520.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 1890 (1 * 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 9)?

Comment: I think you are right, I should try to figure out the iterative way.

Comment: In any case, you'll need to increase `m` because the smallest number divisible by all of `[n,m]` will necessarily be larger than `m`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `smallPos` function incurs undefined behaviour since it is not returning a value in all execution paths. You may want to say `return smallPos(k,n,m);` in the last part (or just `return smallPos(k + 1, n, m);` in one go).

Comment: While this is true, that's not what's causing the stack overflow.

Comment: @Andy: You're right, the OP's function never actually gets to return in the current version... anyway, my UB beats your logical reasoning any day ;-)

Comment: hahaha!  If you bet UB over logical reasoning, there's not reasoning with you and I'll just let you think you've won :-)